# Laravel 5.4 Validation Request , How to handle unique validation on update?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I have a users table which has a unique validate rule on email and username. When i am trying to update not ignore unique validation. Please see my code below.

**UserRequest.php**

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'mobile' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'.$id,
        'usercategory' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username'.$id,
    ];
}
```

Comment: you have used `$id` , from where it is coming ?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```php
public function rules()
{

    $id = $this->request->get('id') ? ',' . $this->request->get('id') : '';

    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'mobile' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'.$id,
        'usercategory' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username'.$id,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 5.5 you should do like this:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Check laravel documentaion about **[rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique)**.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to skip `id` if you validate for update, like as below

```php
public function rules($id='')
{
    $id = $id ? ','.$id.',id':'';
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'mobile' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'.$id,
        'usercategory' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username'.$id,
    ];
}
```

In Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique), you have provide `3rd` and `4th` param in `unique` rule

```
unique:table,column,except,idColumn
```

Comment: @Sandeep : are you sending `$id` to rules function  ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```php
$id = $this->isMethod('put') ? ',' . auth()->id() : '';
```

assuming you use `put` method for update

before line with `return`

Answer (score 0):

for somebody else faced this issue:

```
public function rules()
 {
    return [
    'name' => 'required',
    'mobile' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'.$this->user->id,
    'usercategory' => 'required',
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username'.$this->user->id,
            ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->user->id ?? null;

    return [
        "name" => "required",
        "mobile" => "required",
        "email" => "required|unique:users,email, $id",
        "usercategory" => "required",
        "username" => "required|unique:users,username, $id",
    ];
}
```

Note that for other models other than the User model, the user in `$this->user->id` will be the model name in lowercase